# Calling Java function inside doPost of servlet?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I wanted to process a HTTP request and do some processing on it. Can I do the following?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8");
    char[] cbuf = new char[10000];

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream());

    in.read(cbuf,0,10000);

    int req_len = request.getContentLength(); 

    String inputLine = new String(cbuf);

    Spoof sp = new Spoof();

    String xml_response = sp.spoof_second(inputLine.substring(0, req_len), request.getParameter("mode"));    

    out.println(xml_response);
}
```

I am getting a null response so I wanted to know if there is a way to call the function spoof_second().

My web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
 version="2.4">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>website.web.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

I am sending the request to [http://localhost:4321/website/home?mode=record] so the mode is correct and the inputLine is also correct as I checked by printing them out. The thing I am unsure is on how to build the whole project in Eclipse as I think the function call is not being made. I am not getting any exception and I am getting an HTTP 200 OK response with null content.

Comment: You can call methods inside doPost; you've got something else that's wrong.  I'll bet inputLine is null.

Comment: `doPost` is a method, and method calling inside another method is complete valid in Java, so your problem should be something else, maybe if you post the exception we could help a little more

Comment: System.out xml_response. I think that is being returned as a Null Value.

Comment: There is no exception and when I did out.println(inputLine) its correct. I am deploying the code on Tomcat so I am not sure how to build the project in Eclipse and if I have to save the class files inside any folder. I am just reloading the deployment in Tomcat manager.

Comment: Could you please post the code of this method `sp.spoof_second`

Comment: Its a large code @verisimilitude but you can assume its working as it has been tested well. I have been writing that code for around 5 weeks now and I want to deploy it as a web service now. It basically takes a XML+SOAP request, processes it and returns a XML+SOAP response.

Comment: You could post some excerpts from your code i.e. suspicious code blocks wherein you think that `null` is getting returned... The question in its present context/form is unanswerable.

Comment: I found my mistake, it was some permission problem with a file that I was reading. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using request like `http://localhost:4321/website/home?mode=record` then this will call `doGet`. For do Post, you create and HTML form and set the `action="home"` and `method="post"` and add `submit` button. On that submit it will submit all the data in the form.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: @USArora thats not true, the same request is passed to both the functions doGet and doPost, you can use the same request.getParameter("mode") inside the doPost too.